# Python: How to multiply selection of a colomn of a dataframe (without using a for loop)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I am working with a pandas dataframe, and want to multiply a selection of a specific column. I want to select all the values of `col2` less than 5, and multiply them by 10. How do I do this (without using a 
`for` loop)?

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'col1':[2,3,5,7], 'col2':[1,2,30,4]})
    col1   col2
0   2      1  
1   3      2
2   5      30
3   7      4
```

I tried the following code, but this did not result in the dataframe I want:

```
df['col2'] = df.col2[df['col2']<5]*10
    col1   col2
0   2      10.0 
1   3      20.0
2   5      NaN
3   7      40.0
```

With a `for` loop, I was able to multiply each value smaller than 5 by 10, but the data set i am working on is quite large, so I would rather not use a `for` loop.

```
count=0
for value in df.col2:
    if value < 5:
        df.col2[count]=df.col2[count]*10
        count+=1
```

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: what happens if the value is not less than 5?

Comment: use `np.where` - `np.where(df['col2'].le(5),df['col2'] * 10, df['col2'])`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this with Lambda expression:

```
df["col2"] = df["col2"].apply(lambda x:x*10 if x < 5 else x)
```

I assumed that numbers larger than 10 stay unchanged